# What to wear to an interview at a game development company

Tags: interviewing

What is appropriate attire to wear to an interview at a large, high-profile game development company for a mid-level managerial position (male or female)?

Comment: The real danger here isn't whether you dress properly - it seems like you don't have any acquaintance with anyone presently working there. Lacking insight from people already there, your chances of fitting in are diminished, although probably not by much.

Comment: Hey nycynic, a game dev interview should still be considered a technical interview, so take a look at the linked post for answers. If that doesn't answer your question, please provide more details in an [edit] about the company, the culture, and what you're still confused about.

Comment: There's also these posts, which may be helpful: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/what-is-appropriate-dress-for-a-business-casual-interview, http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11637/can-i-ask-a-company-what-i-should-wear-to-an-interview. In fact, there's a lot of great stuff from a search on our site for [interview+dress](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=interview+dress). Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm going to leave it closed, since it's clearly a small difference, but this question was specifically about game dev. Not sure what the -1 was about.

Comment: I know I'm 3+ years late on this one, but I don't entirely agree that the linked question answers it. The OP specifically asked about interviewing in a certain sub-genre of industry, one that is known even in IT circles for being super casual. The best answer would be one that addresses that sub-genre in particular, or at least one as close as possible, whereas the linked answer is rather broad & generic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that how you [dress for any interview](http://jobsearch.about.com/od/interviewsnetworking/a/dressforsuccess.htm) should always serve this goal : to **Impress**

Always in my interviews,  I wear black slacks, black loafers, light colored long sleeves (tucked in), a necktie (not a noisy one ie too colorful or with a character design) and a black leather coat.

Other applicants might retract and think that you're being overkill or being stand-offish, but  what I wear shows gives off the energy that I am a capable person and I **mean** business. Good business.

You should also be able to project what you wear. Stand up straight, smile whenever it matters and shake hands firmly. You should project confidence.

Of course, what you wear won't matter if you don't have the skills to back it up with, technically and orally.

Comment: Hey Malky, we generally look for answers to contain more than just one line and a link. Consider an [edit] to expand on this with facts, references, your expertise, and even experiences that happened to you personally that help answer the question.

Comment: @jmort253 my apologies, sir. I was hoping the hyperlink could delve into this matter more, but I agree my answer needed a lot more working. I edited as per requirement

Comment: Wow, nice work. For more details on our site and the thought process behind this, check out [the back it up rule](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/255/98), as well as [answer].